# Stuck on splitting strings

Tags: ruby

My goal is to split the string below on space `' '` to get a collection of words in the string.

```
'Fear is the path to the dark side'String#split(',')
```

I cant figure out what method to use. I tried as above and also `.split ('')` and a bunch of others. Any help?

Comment: never mind figured it out. The solution is simply 'Fear is the path to the dark side'.string(" ") Simple enough lol, I was putting ' in the brackets instead.

Comment: `'Fear is the path to the dark side'.split(" ")` not  `'Fear is the path to the dark side'.string(" ")`

Comment: lolololol hahahah rofl

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Same here... *ROFL*.... :-)

Comment: I guess you tried to split the String with a `,` like `'Fear is the path to the dark side'.split(",")` instead of space and as the string is not comma separated you were getting an array with a single string ["Fear is the path to the dark side"] .

Answer (score 4):

You interpreted the document wrong. When a document describes an instance method, you need a way to describe objects in a certain class in general because the method is to be applicable to any instance of the class. The common practice is to write the class name to represent an arbitrary instance of that class. When this is done, the `#` character is used to represent the `.` in order to distinguish it from when you actually want to apply the method to `String`  and not an instance of it. The expression:

```
String#split(',')
```

in the document means to substitute `String` with any instance of `String`, and write `.` instead of `#` like:

```
'Fear is the path to the dark side'.split(',')
```

Then, you have to chose the right argument that will work, which is `" "` in this case.

Comment: This is the actual medicine for this post.. +1

Comment: +1 Good explanation. This is exactly what OP needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just do use [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split)

> If *pattern* is omitted, the value of `$;` is used. If `$;` is `nil` (which is the *default*), `str` is split on *whitespace* as if `' '` were specified.

```
'Fear is the path to the dark side'.split
# => ["Fear", "is", "the", "path", "to", "the", "dark", "side"]
```

Comment: Arup, are you working on something. Have you purblished a gem?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I got the meaning of your questions.. :(

Comment: Arup, you do not need to publish anything, but you need a Github profile. Do not try to force yourself to come up with "something big", but be there in case you want to eg. participate in improving an existing gem.

Comment: You know, if you don't have a Github profile, I cannot nominate you to Ruby hero prize =)

Comment: I still remember you when your Ruby skill was much less than today =)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky My [profile](https://github.com/LoveGitHub).. But very bad, not so impressive.

Comment: @Boris, I fear the day when others say, "I still remember you when your Ruby skill was much greater than today =)".

Comment: @CarySwoveland, you can parry that by creating something of lasting value.

Comment: @Boris, Would many woodworking projects, a handful of publications, hundreds of choice one-liners, two children, and a Nobel prize qualify? I trust you spotted the implicit smiley at the end of my previous comment.  (The Nobel is hypothetical.) I'm sure Arup doesn't mind the banter on his space.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I am afraid Nobel might actually be a [disqualifying factor](http://www.forbes.com/sites/investor/2012/09/19/which-nobel-economists-are-idiots/), but those publications and one-liners intrigue me, can you post a link?

Comment: Boris, I have a few pubs that might interest you.  I'll see if I can find them.  They appeared on April 1 of various years; the rest are vapid scholarly papers. The one-liners reside only in the minds of friends and relatives, and, to an ever-diminishing extent, in my own mind.  Some of my friends complain that they can't get rid themselves of them, much like this [clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72q_yfdYN9k) from Fargo that  @muistooshort referenced in a recent comment. (Thanks a lot, µ). Don't move! A moderator is coming.